# Jquery change .load location

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a menu using the .load function but I don't know how to change the page it's using.

This is what I have...

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="main"></div>
        <script>
            $("#header").load("header.html");
            $("#menu").load("menu.html");
            $("#main").load("main.html");
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

**menu.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-text" id="menu-item1">
                Click me!
            </div>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

So when div id "menu-item1" in **menu.html** is clicked then it should change `$("#main").load("main.html");` to `$("#main").load("OTHERmain.html");` in **index.html** for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="menu-text" id="menu-item1" data-navigate="OTHERmain.html">
    Click me!
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click",".menu-item div",function(){
    $("#main").load($(this).data("navigate"));
});
```

You should use delegated event when dealing with dynamically loaded elements as it simplifies your logic. For more information, look at [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Awesome, nice and clean!

Answer (score 0):

Take avantage of the `data-attributes` like this:

```
<div class="menu-text" id="menu-item1" data-navigate="OTHERmain.html">
    Click me!
</div>
```

then your jquery could be:

```
$(".menu-item div").click(function(){
    $("#header").load($(this).data("navigate"));
});
```

**Edit**:

To make it change when you click on the menu-text element you have to subscribe to the click event:

```
$("#menu-item1").click(function(){
    $("#main").load("OTHERmain.html");
});
```

Now, you have to make sure all of this code is wrapped inside the `document.ready` event:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu-item1").click(function(){
        $("#main").load("OTHERmain.html");
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me... In your code, I also fixed **$(".menu-item div")** to **$(".menu-text div")** and changed **$("#header").load** to **$("#main").load**. **index.html** isn't changing to show **OTHERmain.html**

Comment: I am just giving you ideas. I do not completely understand your bussiness logic, or exactly how it should work.

Comment: I appreciate it. I was just hoping you might be able to tell me why it's not changing when I click on .menu-text div though?

Comment: @ThreaT: The problem is you load page using ajax and bind handler using .click. Use $.on instead

Comment: Thanks Hanlet. It's working now that I've put in your suggested edit.